# VBA - Copy columns A to I to a new worksheet at the end of the book

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote the following that will copy the first worksheet entirely to a new one, at the end of the current workbook.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim test As Worksheet
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set test = ActiveSheet
    test.Name = "copied sheet!"
End Sub
```

However, I figured that I really just need to copy the data in columns A to I only, I don't care of the rest of the columns.

How can I do this please? Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Excel sheets have over 1 million rows, it's always a good habit to limit the range we're acting on:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
With Sheets(1)
    Intersect(.Range("A:I"), .UsedRange).Copy Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
End With
```

or, even faster if we only need to paste values:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
With Sheets(1)
    With Intersect(.Range("A:I"), .UsedRange)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```